# How to edit item in VB6 collection

Tags: vb6

Can you please tell me how to edit item in VB6 collection.
Ex-
I have following collection -

```
Dim OrdLines As New Collection

OrdLines.Add (111)
OrdLines.Add (111)
OrdLines.Add (222)
OrdLines.Add (333)
OrdLines.Add (444)
```

Now my requirement is to edit item 3 and wants to change it let's say "ABC" How can I do this.

Comment: Consider use keys for collection items too - much simpler to delete and (re-)add specfic items.

Comment: What are those parentheses doing there?  See the space added before them by the IDE?  That's a warning that you are not doing what you think you are doing.  Drop them.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can't. You must delete the item and re-add the modified item.

Comment: You are correct I just tried to change one element's value. But, the collection is not updating that.

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve objects by reference and modify them:

SomeClass.cls

```
Option Explicit

Public Value As String
```

Form1.frm

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Col As Collection
    Dim SC As SomeClass

    Set Col = New Collection

    Set SC = New SomeClass
    SC.Value = "hello"
    Col.Add SC

    Set SC = New SomeClass
    SC.Value = "world"
    Col.Add SC

    MsgBox Col(2).Value

    Col(2).Value = "cruel word"

    MsgBox Col(2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the correct way of having editable content in a VB6 collection. Values can't be changed otherwise.

Comment: +1. You can retrieve *references* to *objects* and change their properties.